# Como configurar las cabeceras en angular?

Tags: angular, api, headers, github-pages

**Saludos comunida:**
Recientemente cree una sencilla aplicacion web con angular donde uso la api de Marvel.
En mi servidor de desarrollo local me funciona perfectamente, pero al desplegar a github y usar el servicio de github pages no carga lo que biene desde la api, el error que veo es que la cabecera que retorna agrega la url de github pages antes de la url en la que configuro en el servicio para obtener los datos.

Proyecto completo: https://github.com/webdavs/angularMarvelApp

Despliegue: https://webdavs.github.io/angularMarvelApp/personajes

Agradeceria cualquier ayuda. saludos cordiales.

Comment: Puedes agregar el error que te aparece,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que logro observar de tu código es que estas invocando una URL de esta manera  `URL_API = "https:gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?ts=1&apikey=${this.PUBLIC_KEY}&hash=${this.HASH}"`, te recomiendo cambiar la parte `https: => https://`, de lo contrario estarás invocando el "endpoint" en donde esta alojada tu aplicación de angular.

Comment: Su respuesta fue muy util porque me permitio eliminar un error, pero la solucion final fue importar el servicio en el app.module.ts, no me habia fijado en este detalle. Muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

*Bueno me he tomado la tarea de descargar el proyecto y revisarlo.*

*La verdad, lo que veo que pasa es un tema ya con los routes. Agregale el hash para que en modo producción se logre hacer la separación del proyecto y de las páginas que se solicitan.*

En el archivo app-routing.module.ts modifica el imports de la siguiente manera:

***Como lo tienes:***

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

***Como lo ajusté:***

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

*También invertí los objetos de tu routes y le quité el / en la redirección, para que busque inicialmente la ruta de los personajes, si no existe, lo que sea que reciba lo redireccione a esa pantalla.*

***Como lo tienes:***

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', redirectTo: '/personajes', pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'personajes', component: ListarPersonajesComponent
  }
];
```

***Como lo ajusté:***

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'personajes', component: ListarPersonajesComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**', redirectTo: 'personajes', pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

*Cuando agreges una nueva ruta, lo haces antes del ultimo path, para tu proyecto actual, va a redirigir a la página de personajes, pero si agregas mas, te recomiendo una página de 404 not found o a la pantalla de inicio según lo que vas agregando.*

*espero te sirva,*

*Saludos*

Comment: El error persiste, el tema es que en el servicio al usar get() para obtener los datos de la api esto genera una cabezera que al llevarlo a produccion esta agregando la url de ubicacion del proyecto delante de la url de la api: https://webdavs.github.io/angularMarvelApp/#/personajes, puedes chequear en el navegador inspeccionando el codigo. El tema seria cambiar esa url a la que hace el get() en produccion

Comment: Yo desplegué el proyecto en modo producción y no me generó errores después de los ajustes que le implementé. Los servicios siempre respondieron bien. or eso pedía que mostraras cual era el error. ya que se cargaba bien al inicio todo como lo tenías, pero al refrescar, se dañaba con un 404 not found